# Get the free space available in current directory in Bash

Tags: bash

I know `df -h` and `pwd`, but it seems a little complex for the regex matching part. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean `du -h`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The output can be made a bit easier to parse by using the `-P` option which will ensure that:

> 1. The information about each file system is always printed on
>            exactly one line; a mount device is never put on a line by
>            itself.  This means that if the mount device name is more
>            than 20 characters long (e.g., for some network mounts), the
>            columns are misaligned.

This makes it much easier to get just the free space available:

```
$ df -Ph . | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

(`-h` uses megabytes, gigabytes and so on. If your system doesn't have it, use `-k` for kilobytes only.)

If we pass `df` a path, it is only going to return 2 rows: a header row and then the data about the file system that contains the path. We can use tail to grab just the second row.  We know that the space available is in the 4th column, so we grab that with `awk`.  This all could be done with `awk`:

```
$ df -Ph . | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'
```

or many other sets of [filters](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch11s06.html#id2957637).

Comment: You can optimize your command by using the environment variable `$PWD` instead of using command substitution and removing the need for tail:  `df -Ph $PWD | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'`

Comment: @SiegeX: I agree doing it all in `awk` is better.  I included the longer command because I wanted to have an example of how one can construct a chain of simple commands to do something more complicated.  I've updated the answer to include your improvement.

Comment: `-P` is standard (the `P` is for POSIX). But `-h` is a GNU extension (also existing on some other systems, but e.g. on OpenBSD it's incompatible with `-P`).

Comment: You can do this without out by using the --output=avail switch: 
``df -h --output=avail . | tail -1``

Comment: "You can optimize your command". Not really. Running both pipes 10'000 times (as in  `time { I=0; while [ $I -lt 10000 ]; do  df -Ph . | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}' > /dev/null; ((I++)); done }`) reveals no meaningful difference in speed, which is not astonishing - invoking `tail` isn't expensive and `awk` will be spared to skip to the end of the input... There might have been a difference on the PDP-11...

Answer (score 22):

How about doing `df -h .`. This will give you the available free space of the partition your current working directory is in.

A small example:

```
 /usr/local/nagios/libexec # df -h .
 Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol1
                       9.9G  6.1G  3.4G  65% /
```

Answer (score 8):

In bytes:

```
df --output=avail -B 1 "$PWD" | tail -n 1
```

Human readable:

```
df --output=avail -h "$PWD" | tail -n 1
```

or

```
df --output=avail -B 1 "$PWD" |tail -n 1 | numfmt --to="iec"
```

or

```
df --output=avail -B 1 "$PWD" |tail -n 1 | numfmt --grouping
```

Answer (score 2):

You can **simply** do it like this:

```
df -h $PWD | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'
```

**Command Interpretation:**

`df`: (disk free) is a standard Unix command used to display the amount of available disk space for file systems on which the invoking user has appropriate read access.

`-h`: to show the output in a human-readable format i.e. megabytes, gigabytes, and so on.

`$PWD`: Invoke the command in the current directory.

`|`: pass the output of the leftmost command to the rightmost one.

`awk`: is a utility that enables a programmer to scan each input file for lines that match any of a set of patterns specified literally in prog or in one or more files specified as -f file.

`'NR==2`: Get the second row that contains the space numeric value, not the header -NR==1-.

'{print $4}': Get the 4th column which contains the available space.